# c# blend создание кнопок

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blend

Как в Blend с помощью кода создать кнопку и присвоить ей шаблон программно ?

Comment: я так понимаю мне нужно через c# редактировать xaml

Comment: Вы сейчас обозначили 2 вопроса. С каким конкретно у вас проблемы?

Comment: мне нужно есть скрипт который создает кнопки, мне нужно чтобы при создании кнопок создавался кнопка и применялся мой шаблон(который я создал в blend) кнопки

Comment: Шаблон ваш в XAML?

Comment: да в xaml мой шаблон

Comment: А кнопки вы как создаете? В XAML объявляете?

Comment: да я сделал кастомную кнопку в blend в XAML, и есть у меня код в котором кнопки создаются но создаются они обычные как по умолчанию а мне нужно к ним применить шаблон кастомной кнопки...

Comment: Вы кнопке шаблон как задаете? `<Button Template="{DynamicResource MyButtonTemplate}"/>` - так пробовали?

Comment: это я знаю как задать как мне это реализовать через c# чтобы она в xaml писал создание кнопки или через сам c# присвоить шаблон

Comment: у меня метод createbutton через Button new = new Button(); он создает кнопку и добавляет её на flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newButton);

Comment: и вот как мне в этот метод впихнуть присвоение шаблона который в xaml создан

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам подойдет следующий код:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Style = (Style)Resources["myButtonStyle"];
myGrid.Children.Add(button);
```

При этом стиль лежит в ресурсах окна `<Window.Resources>`, если стиль лежит в ресурсах другого контрола или в `Application` - укажите его: `myGrid.Resources[...`

Аналогично для `Template`:

```
button.Template = (Template)Resources["myButtonTemplate"];
```

Comment: у меня почему то не применяется шаблон.... хотя если я ничего не задаю, то он делает по умолчанию который я создал и тот по умолчанию успешно применяется......

Comment: @bandy07, показывайте код